# NSString subsstring

Tags: ios, nsstring, substring

I have a string like this

12,23,45,3,12,

What I want to do is get this each number and check with an array value. How I can get each value as a substring to check

Thanks

Comment: do you want to check for these 6 values if they exists in an array ? or you want to check if any of them exists in the array?

Comment: want to check all 6 values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break this string to array.

```
NSString *string = @"12,23,45,3,12,";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Then you can compare with the array.

**EDIT :**

As per your comment that you want to check all the string values to be present in main-other-array.

```
NSString *string = @"12,23,45,3,12";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
//below is the main-other-array
NSArray *toCheckArray = @[@"124",@"23",@"45",@"3",@"12",@"1000"];

BOOL arrayIsContainedInToCheckArray = YES;

for (NSString *arrayObj in array) {
    if (![toCheckArray containsObject:arrayObj]) {
        arrayIsContainedInToCheckArray = NO;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",arrayIsContainedInToCheckArray?@"All exist":@"All doesn't exist");
```

Answer (score 2):

May be it helps you :

```
NSString *str = @"12,23,45,3,12";
NSArray *strArray = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray * anotherArray = nil; // have some value
for (NSString * value in strArray)
{
    int intVal = [value integerValue]; // here is your separate value
    for (int i = 0; i < [anotherArray count]; i++) // You can check against another array
    {
        id anotherVal = [anotherArray objectAtIndex:i];

        // Here you can check intVal and anotherVal from another array

    }
}
```

Comment: nested loop will be overkilling

Answer (score 1):

Use this, It will help you..

```
NSArray *detailArray = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```